# Tabbing on Form disappears when using Control.FromHandle

Tags: vb.net, winforms, handle, floating

VB2010: I have a form that I display within a mapping application that supports their framework through .NET. So when the user clicks a button on a custom extension then my form will be displayed.

```vb
Private frm As New frmDesigner 'since this is a floating form

Public Overrides Sub OnClick()
    Try
        ''display the form normally
        'Dim frm As New frmDesigner
        'frm.ShowDialog()

        'display the modeless form and the form will always be on top of the main app.
        If frm.IsDisposed Then frm = New frmDesigner 'To handle user closing form
        If frm.Visible Then
            frm.BringToFront()
        Else
            Dim appCtr As Control = Control.FromHandle(CType(MyApp.hWnd, IntPtr))
            frm.Show(appCtr)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        DisplayException(ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

This works great and I have been using this approach for a couple years now. The problem that I am seeing now is that the tabbing through controls on the form does not work. Once the form appears I press on the Tab button and the cursor does not tab through the controls. I can set focus on a textbox through the mouse and then attempt to tab over to the next control but that doesn't work either.

If I display the form normally through frm.ShowDialog then the tabbing does work. Is there something I am missing here to make the tabbing work properly?

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with FromHandle().  The shortcut and navigation keys can only work when it is Application.Run() that is in control.  It is not, it is the host app that is doing the dispatching.  ShowDialog() is necessary to revive them.

Comment: So if my ultimate goal is to have a floating form that sits on top of the main app but is modeless is there any way to do that without these side effects? Asides from the KeyDown on every control?

Comment: I ended up using the workaround from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133402/windows-form-tab-key-does-not-work-in-a-child-panel